# How to free up agents from wait block under a certain condition in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

```
List<Bulk_Container> L1 = findAll(wait3, p -> p.Board_Type == agent.Board_Type);
// Create a list of products that belong to the same client as the agent that arrived.
int orderSize = 0;
if(agent.quantity>0){
orderSize = agent.quantity+1;
}
if (L1.size() == orderSize) {
    // Check if the batch size is reached.
    batch1.set_batchSize(agent.quantity);

    for (Bulk_Container p : L1) {
        wait3.free(p);
    }
} else {
    // Handle the case when the mother agent arrives early.
    // Use the mother agent's quantity as a local variable.
    int motherAgentQuantity = agent.quantity;
    // Additional logic here...
    // Place your code here to handle the early arrival scenario.
}
```

I have some containers waiting in the block with agent.quantity = 0. And another agent( Order actually but of the same agent type as the previous one), which has the agent.quantity>0.

Now the challenge is,

If the order agent arrives first in the wait block, I am not able to get the agent.quantity value when the other agents arrive. Please note that, other agents are just waiting in wait block with no label.

But if the order agent arrives later, its just fine. So my imagination is, is there a way I can use the value of the order agent everytime the other agent arrives???

So I just to need to get the exact type of product with the value Board_Type.